# Change the main screen in persistent_bottom_nav_bar flutter

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

Initially the main screen page of the [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) is the first page under the list screen: (In my case the first page in the list is FormPage()), but I want the Home() page which is at index 1 to be the main screen page. The app should close on the Home() screen and not on the FormPage(). I tried to change the initial index in controller as shown in the code, after that my Home() page does open but when I press the back button instead of closing it goes to the FormPage() screen.

```
class _PersistentNavBarState extends State<PersistentNavBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PersistentTabController _controller;

    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 1);

    List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
      return [
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(MdiIcons.fileDocumentEditOutline),
          title: ("Form"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.grey[100]!,
          activeColorSecondary: Colors.black,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.black,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: ("Home"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.grey[100]!,
          activeColorSecondary: Colors.black,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.black,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: ("Profile"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.grey[100]!,
          activeColorSecondary: Colors.black,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.black,
        ),
      ];
    }

    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      padding: NavBarPadding.only(left: 10, right: 10),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: [FormPage(), Home(), ProfilePage()],
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar situation, after doing tons of RnD haven't found any fix for the issue, but I have managed a workaround to tackle the requirement. You can use the ***jumpToTab(int tabIndex)*** method from the **PersistentTabController** instance in the **PersistentTabView** package.
I have persisted the controller in a custom state manager instance and then invoke the ***jumpToTab(int tabIndex)*** method with desired tab index.

```
AppStateManager.persistentTabController.jumpToTab(tabIndex);
```